# Result is wrong in Selenium XPATH

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have a Python Selenium xpath problem. The html structure is as follows:

```html
<li class="searchResultItem">
                    <div class="view_items">
                        <div class="img pruImage">
 
                     </div>
                        <div class="name pro_Imgs" data-productid="520355">

                        </div>
                        <div class="price">
                            €789.99
                            <span class="list-price">
                            €1025.13</span>
                        </div>
```

With the locator

```py
product_preis_neu = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//li[@class="searchResultItem"]/div[1]/div[3]')
```

I unfortunately get both the price and the list-price under <span, e.g. €949.99\n€1109.83.
How can I achieve that I just get only product_preis_neu without the list-price under <span?
Thanks for help

I get preis_neu\nprice-list. I expect only preis_neu

Comment: I need a right locator for preis_neu